Nixos, is it possible to "alias" a library's name?
I'm daily driving NixOS and I'm trying to go back at developing Flutter applications. I'm currently trying to build (flutter run) the LocalSend app.
Problem: This app has the system_tray dependency (See on Pub.dev  or Github). The issue resides in the fact that the system_tray package depends on the ayatana-appindicator library (See the compiling error below):
$> flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode...
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/system_tray/linux/CMakeLists.txt:29 (message):


  The `system_tray` package requires ayatana-appindicator3-0.1 or
  appindicator3-0.1.


"No big deal" I thought at first, I only have to install this library. After searching on Nix packages, I find the libayatana-appindicator package. Great ! So I run nix-shell -p libayatana-appindicator and then re-run flutter run but I still get the same error. I thought it was maybe not the right package so I tried all the packages listed here but still the same error.
After digging in the system_tray package's repo I found this line in linux/CMakeList.txt:
pkg_check_modules(APPINDICATOR IMPORTED_TARGET ayatana-appindicator3-0.1)

So the issue seems to be that this line is looking specifically for the ayatana-appindicator3-0.1 package and doesn't find it because it is named libayatana-appindicator on NixOs.
So my question would be: How can I 'alias' libayatana-appindicator as ayatana-appindicator3-0.1 so the  compiler can find it ? Or maybe if you have any idea that would work better I'd love it too.
Thanks for reading, I hope I have managed to clearly express my issue and thought process.
